# 'ngc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angular, npm

Tried all the solution on web but none of them is working, can someone please help ?

```
C:\Users\<username>\Downloads\Copies\TryAngularv4masterWithChangesOfUniversalButNotWorking>ng build --prod && ngc && webpack
Date: 2018-08-25T14:21:08.094Z
Hash: 83a6b1ff1c57a20b3f5c
Time: 44628ms
chunk {0} runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js (runtime) 1.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.246773ba9e0bac43b3c6.js (main) 603 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.3f11bf9959f924754af3.js (polyfills) 64.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.e1de924f6916038db79f.css (styles) 781 bytes [initial] [rendered]
```

following error I am getting

> 'ngc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try to delete node_modules folder and try again

Comment: @Sajeetharan I tried deleting node_modules and ran the command npm install but still I am getting same error